# How to modify this regex to include https?

Tags: php, regex

I have this piece of regex that I'm using to create clickable links from URLs entered into a textarea. I did not write the code and am not sure how to modify it so that it will create links if the text starts with either http or https.

```
$html = preg_replace('"\b(http://\S+)"', '<a href="$1">$1</a>', stripslashes($rows['body']));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding a `?` to the regex makes the preceding character optional.

```
$html = preg_replace('"\b(https?://\S+)"', '<a href="$1">$1</a>', stripslashes($rows['body']));
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
\b(http://\S+)
```

with:

```
\b(https?://\S+)
```

All together:

```
$html = preg_replace('"\b(https?://\S+)"', '<a href="$1">$1</a>', stripslashes($rows['body']));
```

Answer (score 0):

No regex expert, so this might work:

```
$html = preg_replace('"\b(http://\S+|https://\S+)"', '<a href="$1">$1</a>', stripslashes($rows['body']));
```